# Eclipse Kepler Java Template Doesn't Work With an Indented Brace

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, eclipse-kepler

I am using Kepler and have been trying to modify the default template for "for - iterate over array" at Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates.  The default is:

```
for (int ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${array}.length; ${index}++) {
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
}
```

and I simply want to indent the closing brace so that we have:

```
for (int ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${array}.length; ${index}++) {
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
    }
```

The change is being saved (I can return and see the indented brace) but when I try to use this in a .java file by typing "for" the popup list shows "for - iterate over array" with the original non-indented brace and when I select that I get the default/non-indented brace as:

```
for (int ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${array}.length; ${index}++) {
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
}
```

If I make some other change to the template such as:

```
for (int ${index} = 0; ${index} < ${array}.length; ${index}++) {
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
    THIS IS JUST A TEST
    }
```

I get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bBPMN2.length; i++) {

    THIS IS JUST A TEST
}
```

The new text is used (although I don't know why I get the blank line) so that suggests to me that the template is being activated.  So it seems that I just can't get an indented closing brace.  I am wondering if there is some other "format" setting that is overriding the indentation on my closing brace but I can't find anything.  Not that I can see why it would make a difference but I have tried this with "Use code formatter" turned off and it makes no difference.

How can I get an indented closing brace?

Thank you.
Al

Comment: I suspect the indentation is superseded by the indentation rules found in Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter.  The closest I could find to what you want is on the Braces tab if you click the Edit button on a profile.  There you'll be able to set 'blocks' in general to put braces on "next line indented".  It's not quite what you want because the opening brace is also on a new line and indented.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  You are right, that does get me the indented closing brace but then I have the opening brace on a new line which I don't want.  I don't think I'm being "overridden" by anything here because I have tried the Template with "Use code formatter" turned off and I still don't get the indent.  The template allows me to indent the closing brace so it seems that either there is a bug or there is another setting that's "overriding" the indent in the template.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again. Al